# Explanation for output in Python

Tags: python

I came across a piece of python code, requiring me to give the output. The code goes as follows:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [a, 3]
c = b[:]
a[0] = 7
b[1] = 8
print c
```

I thought the output to be `[[7, 2], 8]` since i have the reference to the `a` in `b`, and consequently, `c` had the reference to `b`

But the output came out to be `[[7, 2], 3]`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Unlike `c = b` `c = b[:]` creates a (flat) copy of `b` as `c`. Changes in `b` are not reflected to `c`.

Comment: `c = b[:]` is a shallow copy

Comment: have a look to this:https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/shallow-deep-copy

Comment: @KlausD. if changes in `b` are not reflected in `c` , how come the changes in `a` are getting reflected in `c` ?

Comment: @ssein thanks, it really cleared a lot of concepts!

Comment: Because it is a flat (aka shallow) copy. The list as a sequence to references to objects is copied. The objects are not, they remain the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `c` had the reference to `b`

This is where you went wrong.  `c` is initialized as a (shallow) copy of `b`.

If it were simply `c = b` (without the `[:]`) then you'd be correct.

Comment: Had to clear a lot of concepts about shallow copy and deep copy. Thanks for the response. Marking it as accepted!